# Open edge 10.2B -impact on migration of Solaris 10 to Solaris 11

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl, progress-db

We have application set up on Openedge 10.1c on Solaris 10. We are planning a migration to 10.2B on Solaris 10 to Solaris 11.

Do we need to re-compile all programs due to OE and OS version change?

Do we need a dump and load instead of a dB refresh?

Answer (score 1):

No, you are not required to re-compile.  Nor is it a requirement to dump & reload the db.

For a point-release upgrade:

- shutdown the db
- truncate the bi file, if you are extra paranoid make a backup
- apply the upgrade (or change the link pointing to the upgraded install directory)
- run "proutil dbname -C updatevsts"
- restart the db

On UNIX it is very common to have the old version and new version installed simultaneously.  You can manage this very easily by using a naming scheme similar to:

```
/usr/oe101c    # the 10.1c install directory
/usr/oe102b    # the 10.2b install directory
/usr/dlc       # a link to whichever one you want to be "live"
```

(You can also use the $DLC variable to redirect sessions, perhaps for testing purposes.  Many times people use a simple shell script to set the DLC, PATH & PROPATH to dynamically switch between versions.)

You are not required to re-compile.  But once you have migrated to 10.2b and you are sure that you are not going to revert it is a "best practice" to re-compile.  That way your code can start to take advantage of new features.

Having said all of that - 10.2B is very old.  You really ought to be upgrading to OpenEdge 11.something  (11.7.3 is current at the moment.)

If you can compile code there is no reason to stick with version 10.  Upgrading to oe11 will, however, require a recompile.

You can also upgrade from 10 to 11 without dumping and re-loading.  You can just add "proutil dbname -C conv1011" to the steps above.

(Dumping and re-loading may have benefits but that is a different conversation. Migration between versions or platforms is often a convenient time to do it.)

If you are going to ignore me and stick with version 10 at least go with 10.2b service pack 08.  That is the very last release of OpenEdge 10 and it has numerous bug fixes and enhancements that vanilla 10.2b lacks.

Changing Solaris versions does not matter with regards to needing to recompile or dump & load.

You should, of course, still test everything and not just take my word  for it.

Comment: Thanks a lot Tom. I am going to propose the version upgrade in the next meeting. Thanks once again!

Comment: The question actually seems to mention a migration from Solaris 10 to 11. Not OpenEdge 10 to 11?

Comment: Would change in the OS version have an impact? Please do suggest.

Comment: Changing Solaris versions should not matter, it certainly doesn't cause you to need to recompile or dump & load.  But, FWIW, Solaris is becoming very rare in the Progress world.  Personally I would almost certainly suggest moving to Linux if this kind of thing came up at a customer site.

Comment: @jensd I  took the main thrust to be 10.1c to 10.2b and added that 11 would be a much better target than 10.  But I overlooked the simultaneous Solaris update aspect of the question.  I've added a comment about that.

Comment: Thanks Tom and Jensd!